# How to asynchronously check if a username is already taken with formControl?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my method where i try to check from the database which usernames are already taken:

```
takenUsernames(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((employees) => {
        this.employees = employees;
        for (let employee of control.value) {
          if (this.employees.indexOf(employee) !== -1) {
            resolve({ usernameIsTaken: true });
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

And this is my formGroup object:

```
this.newProjectForm = new FormGroup({
      projectName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(null),
      assignedEmployees: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      employees: new FormArray(
        [],
        [this.forbidUsernames.bind(this)],
        [this.takenUsernames.bind(this)]
      ),
    });
```

As you can see employees is a FormArray so i loop true control.value to check each username but it doesnt seem to work. The problem is in the takenUsernames function because i dont get the pending status if i inspect the element.

Here's the whole html code:

```
link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@500&display=swap"
  type="text"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<div class="backdrop" (click)="onFormAlertClose()"></div>
<div class="alert-box">
  <form [formGroup]="newProjectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <h3>New Project Form</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="projectName">Project Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="projectName"
        class="form-control"
        [formControlName]="'projectName'"
      />
      <!-- if omit [] also omit ''-->
      <span
        *ngIf="
          !newProjectForm.get('projectName').valid &&
          newProjectForm.get('projectName').touched
        "
        >Please enter a project name</span
      >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea
        id="description"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="description"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="assignedEmployees">Assign Employees</label>
      <div class="larger-width-divider"></div>
      <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search..." />
      <select
        name="employees"
        class="form-control"
        multiple
        size="employees.length"
        formControlName="assignedEmployees"
      >
        <ng-container *ngIf="newProjectForm.get('projectName').valid">
          <option id="option" *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{
            employee.userName
          }}</option>
        </ng-container>
      </select>
      <span
        *ngIf="
          !newProjectForm.get('assignedEmployees').valid &&
          newProjectForm.get('assignedEmployees').touched
        "
        >Please select at least one employee</span
      >
    </div>
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="add-emp-btn"
        *ngIf="!addEmployeeBtnClicked"
        (click)="onEmpBtnClicked()"
        [disabled]="newProjectForm.invalid"
      >
        Add Employees
      </button>
      <ng-container *ngIf="addEmployeeBtnClicked" formArrayName="employees">
        <div *ngFor="let employeesControl of getControls(); let i = index">
          <label for="userName">Insert one or multiple employee</label>
          <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" />
          <div class="width-divider"></div>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="goto-add-emp-btn"
            (click)="onEmpBtnClicked()"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <div>
            <span
              class="last-span"
              *ngIf="
                !newProjectForm.get('employees').valid &&
                newProjectForm.get('employees').touched
              "
            >
              <span
                *ngIf="newProjectForm.get('employees').errors?.nameIsForbidden"
                >This name is invalid!</span
              >
              <span *ngIf="newProjectForm.get('employees').errors?.required"
                >Add at least on employee</span
              >
              <span
                *ngIf="newProjectForm.get('employees').errors?.usernameIsTaken"
              ></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="height-divider"></div>
    <div class="alert-box-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="submit" [disabled]="!newProjectForm.valid">
        Create
      </button>
      <div class="width-divider"></div>
      <button type="button" (click)="onFormAlertClose()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here's the whole class:

```
import { Component, Output, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ProjectService } from "src/app/services/project.service";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from "@angular/forms";
import { IEmployee } from "../entities/employee";
import { EmployeeService } from "src/app/services/employee.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-alert",
  templateUrl: "./new-project-form-alert.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./new-project-form-alert.component.css"],
})
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  closeNewProjectAlert: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  employees: IEmployee[];
  newProjectForm: FormGroup;
  addEmployeeBtnClicked = false;
  forbiddenUsernames = [
    "Admin",
    "Manager",
    "Developer",
    "Guest",
    "admin",
    "manager",
    "developer",
    "guest",
  ];

  constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((employees) => {
      this.employees = employees;
    });
    this.newProjectForm = new FormGroup({
      // properties are string so when the files is minified they are not destroyed
      projectName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(null),
      assignedEmployees: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      employees: new FormArray(
        [],
        [this.forbidUsernames.bind(this)],
        this.takenUsernames
      ),
    });
  }

  onFormAlertClose() {
    this.projectService.closeNewProjectForm$.next(true);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.newProjectForm);
    this.newProjectForm.reset();
    this.onFormAlertClose();
    console.log((<FormArray>this.newProjectForm.get("employees")).controls);
  }

  onEmpBtnClicked() {
    if (!this.addEmployeeBtnClicked) {
      this.addEmployeeBtnClicked = true;
      const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
      (<FormArray>this.newProjectForm.get("employees")).push(control);
    } else {
      this.addEmployeeBtnClicked = false;
      (<FormArray>this.newProjectForm.get("employees")).removeAt(0);
    }
  }

  forbidUsernames(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    for (let employee of control.value) {
      if (this.forbiddenUsernames.indexOf(employee) !== -1) {
        return { nameIsForbidden: true };
      }
    }
    return null; // this if username is valid, do not return false
  }

  takenUsernames(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      const observable = this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((employees) => {
        this.employees = employees;
        for (let employee of control.value) {
          if (this.employees.indexOf(employee) !== -1) {
            resolve({ usernameIsTaken: true });
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }

  getControls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.newProjectForm.get("employees")).controls;
  }
}
```

Sorry i know it a big mess, it's my first web app.

Edit: i provided a small video of the form if it helps: https://streamable.com/ua7mcq

Comment: everything seems working fine. may be you can not catch a moment where request is not yet complete, because it is very fast?

Comment: well when i tipe a username there is no status changes in inspect element. i will provide the whole html code and class

Comment: is what you are typing passing synchronious validators first?

Comment: yes before the takenUsernames there is a sincronous validator called forbidUsernames with hardcoded invalid usernames

Comment: check the network tab, during your edits. are there http calls in there?

Comment: Ok so let me redo the comment. I binded (this) to the validator takenUsernames and now the calls are fired everytime i tipe a character in the correct input. 

But the whole validity of the form is messed up, it let me create the user with a taken username and submit the form

Comment: @Andrei goddamn im must doint the comparison between usernames and employee not employee username from the http request. i have to change the check in the validator

Answer (score 0):

Well yep, i have named the formArray as employees because when i submit the form the username or usernames get added to IEmployee objects and saved in the database.

But of the time of typing the usernames they are just string and i was comparing these strings with the employee objects.
So here's it fixed:

```
takenUsernames(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      const observable = this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((employees) => {
        this.employees = employees;
        const usernames = this.employees.map(employee => employee.userName)
        console.log(usernames)
        for (let employee of control.value) {
          if (usernames.indexOf(employee) !== -1) {
            resolve({ usernameIsTaken: true });
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

But now i will reduce the input box to be able to add just one employee at time, wasted too much time on these component.